# Image science1.2.1 fails to load in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-science

I am trying to run my application and bundle install worked fine for me.. I am using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2 amd image science 1.2.1 But when I use rails server the imagescience is failing to compile I guess and shows the following error...  Does anyone have any idea...??Please help...

```
C:\Users\Webyana Tech\Desktop\Rails3\wy_editor>rails server
script/rails: No such file or directory - gcc -shared $(if $(filter-out -g -g0,-g),,-s)   -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import $(DEFFILE)

   -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings

-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -I C:/Ruby192/
include/ruby-1.9.1 -I C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby192/include

 -LC:/Ruby192/lib -o "C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_
ImageScience_cdab.so" "C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c" 

-lfreeimage -lfreeimage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/
Ruby192/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RubyInline-3.9.0/lib/inline.rb:590:in `build': error executing "gcc -shared $(if $(filter-out -g -g0,-g),,-s)   -W
l,

--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import $(DEFFILE)   -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wn
o-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -I C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby192/include -L

C:/Ruby192/lib -o \"C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.so\" \"C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c\" -l
freeimage -lfreeimage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby192/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18":  (CompilationError)


Renamed C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c to C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c.bad
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RubyInline-3.9.0/lib/inline.rb:828:in `inline'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/image_science-1.2.1/lib/image_science.rb:90:in `<class:ImageScience>'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/image_science-1.2.1/lib/image_science.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'

        from C:/Users/Webyana Tech/Desktop/Rails3/wy_editor/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'

        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to compile imagescience. Windows doesn't have a compiler so it is throwing an error. Try to get a windows version of imagescience...or better, change your OS

Comment: I couldn't locate the windows verison of image science 1.2.1.. Is there any windows image science of version 1.2.1?? Please let me know

Comment: if there is none then it's better to just change your dev environment.try using ubuntu(it's free and there's an installer for windows so you can dual boot and not do any partitioning stuff)